# How specify pre-commit --from-ref for Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pre-commit.com

I want to check by pre-commit files that was changed in git branch in Gitlab CI. What arg for `--from-ref` I need to use?

```sh
pre-commit run --from-ref=? --to-ref=HEAD
```

Example from `pre-commit` documentation raises error.

```
$ pre-commit run --from-ref=origin/HEAD --to-ref HEAD
An unexpected error has occurred: CalledProcessError: command: ('/usr/bin/git', 'diff', '--name-only', '--no-ext-diff', '-z', 'origin/HEAD...HEAD')
return code: 128
expected return code: 0
stdout: (none)
stderr:
    fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/HEAD...HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
    Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
    'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Comment: It took me so long to find this exactly question, specifically for GitLab CICD. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same issue while developing a pre-commit stage for a GitLab CI/CD pipeline. It seems that the GitLab CI/CD runner does not automatically fetch the `origin/master` branch, leading to the `fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/HEAD...HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.` error.

My workaround was to manually fetch `origin`:

```
git fetch origin;
pre-commit run --from-ref "origin/$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH" --to-ref "$CI_COMMIT_SHA";
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is helpful for anyone looking for the **GitHub Actions** version of this. This post inspired me, and I ended up setting up pre-commit on GitHub Actions with the following setup and arguments (run as a bash script):

```
pip install pre-commit
git fetch origin
pre-commit run --from-ref origin/${{ github.event.pull_request.base.ref }} --to-ref ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was battling this, too, and I finally got the answer.

1. Before running pre-commit at all, fetch the `origin/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME`. In most cases, this will be `origin/master`, but we want to stay flexible.
2. Then, run pre-commit from the fetched target branch to `$CI_COMMIT_SHA`.

This is what your `script` should look like:

```yaml
script:
  - git fetch origin $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME
  - pre-commit run --from-ref origin/"$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME" --to-ref "$CI_COMMIT_SHA"
```

Answer (score -1):

To answer the question:

```
variables:
  GIT_FETCH_EXTRA_FLAGS: $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH --prune
script:
  - pre-commit run --from-ref origin/$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH --to-ref $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
```

==============

In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70583921/20263129):

Since GitLab 13.1 theres the GIT_FETCH_EXTRA_FLAGS variable to control behavior of git fetch command. Default is

```
git fetch origin $REFSPECS --depth $GIT_DEPTH  --prune --quiet
```

(see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#git-fetch-extra-flags)

So theres no need to add `git fetch`.